# Generating MySql scheme from Doctrine (using ZF2)

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Are there any third party tools that can generate a Mysql database from a doctrine scheme?

I am using ZF2 with Doctrine Orm 2 with Skipper to generate my entities. However when it comes to generating my MySql database I do this via Workbench. The problem is that this DB does not always follow the changes and updates I make to the Skipper files.

Now I know I can update via Doctrine's vendor folder using the tool provided, however I have never been able to get this to work due to other vendor modules crashing the environment while in console mode. ZfcRbac / Oauth2 and others that just done play nicely when in command line.

So my question is simply, is there an easy third party tool I can use to save time and frustration or at least some other technique I can use?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to synchronize your database is to use [Doctrine Migrations](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html). Every time when you update your entities, it does not matter how - manually or with Skypper, you should create a migration. My workflow is:

1) I modify some entity, let say adding a new property;

2) Then I use Doctrine orm tool to generate the entity accessors. /If you already have them, generated by Skypper, you can skip this step/

```
$php public/index.php orm:generate-entities --update-entities="true" --generate-methods="true" module/Application/src
```

3) **Updated**: Generate doctrine proxies

```
$php public/index.php orm:generate:proxies
```

4) The next step is to generate the migrations:

```
$php public/index.php migrations:diff
```

5) And the final step is to execute the migration and get your database synchronized with the new schema:

```
$php public/index.php migrations:migrate
```

That's all, now your database is synchronized. I am not sure if there is a third party library for this. If you have problems with the other modules, it is a good idea to check your configurations trying to fix them.

Comment: Does this mean you no longer use doctrine:schema:update?

Comment: Yes, I do not use doctrine:schema:update, only the steps described above.